# Python Cryptography Error with Decryption

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I am working on a piece of code which takes an input, writes it to a text file then reads the text file, decrypts it and prints the output. Everything is working except for the decrypt part of my code. I have two linescommented out above. They were also producing errors which led me to believe it is a problem with my decryption.

```
import cryptography
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
import os.path

doc = open("cryptest.txt", "a+")
query = input('Type the text to be encrypted:').encode('utf-8')
print(query + ' is the query'.encode('utf-8'))

key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
cipher_text = f.encrypt(query)
#plain_text = f.decrypt(query)
#plain_text = f.decrypt(cipher_text)


doc.write("\n" + str(cipher_text))
doc.close() #closes file
open1 = open("cryptest.txt", "r") #opens file to read it
#open2 = open1.encode('utf-8')
print(open1.read() + 'is the contents of the text document')
#print (f.decrypt(open2.read())) #prints whatever is in the text file 
plaint = open1.read().encode('utf-8')
print(plaint +'is the encoded contents of the file'.encode('utf-8'))
decrypto = f.decrypt(plaint)
print(str(decrypto) + 'is the decrypted information'.encode('utf-8'))

doc.close()
```

The error I am getting is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\CryptoTut.py", line 25, in <module>
decrypto = f.decrypt(plaint)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 74, in decrypt
timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 88, in _get_unverified_token_data
raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/), the `encrypt()` method raises a `TypeError` exception if the argument type is not bytes. You appear to be passing a string. Try `decrypto = f.decrypt(bytes(plaint,'utf-8'))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking more closely at the documentation it seems that there is a timestamp associated with the data being encrypted and will not decrypt without this. This is lost when the encrypted text is turned into a string and written to a text file. It may be possible to use sqlite as it may have a proper data type for the timestamped data.